# how to cancel previous axios with redux in react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios

i have the following action in my action file.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
var source = CancelToken.source();

export const FETCH_WORKERJOBS = 'fetch_workerjobs';

export function fetchWorkerJobs(page, size, where, sort) {
    const request = axios.get(`/api/user/report/comms/matrix/upload/format/json?quiet=1&page=`+page+`&size=`+size+`&where=`+JSON.stringify(where)+`&sort=`+sort,{cancelToken: source.token});   
    return {
        type: FETCH_WORKERJOBS,
        payload: request
    };
}

export const FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT = 'fetch_workerjobs_count';

export function fetchWorkerJobsCount(where) {
    const request = axios.get(`/api/user/report/comms/matrix/upload/count/format/json?quiet=1&where=`+JSON.stringify(where), {cancelToken: source.token});  
    return {
        type: FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

How can i access the `cancel` token to cancel when I am importing the function into my component

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchWorkerJobs, fetchWorkerJobsCount } from '../../actions';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { Button, ButtonToolbar, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import {
    BootstrapTable,
    TableHeaderColumn,
    InsertModalHeader,
    InsertModalFooter
} from 'react-bootstrap-table';
import 'react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

const jobType = {
        }

class WorkerJobs extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.workerJobs = [];
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            show: false,
            showError: false,
            errorMsg: '',
            errorTitle: '',
            record: {},
            showEdit: false,
            confirm: {
                body: '',
                show: false,
                id: ''
            },
            totalDataSize: 0,
            currentPage: 1

        };
        this.where = {};
        this.sort = 'worker_job_id desc';
        this.meta = { title: 'Report - Worker Jobs', description: 'List of jobs processed' };
        this.error = {show: false,msg:''};
        this.passMetaBack = this.passMetaBack.bind(this);
        this.options = {
            defaultSortName: 'worker_job_id', // default sort column name
            defaultSortOrder: 'desc', // default sort order
            page: 1,
            paginationShowsTotal: true,
            sizePerPage: 10,
            sizePerPageList: [10,25,50],
            onPageChange: this.onPageChange.bind(this),
            onSizePerPageList: this.onSizePerPageList.bind(this),
            onFilterChange: this.onFilterChange.bind(this),
            onSortChange: this.onSortChange.bind(this)
        };

        this.fetchWorkerJobs = this.fetchWorkerJobs.bind(this);

        this.runOnce = false;
    }

    onPageChange(page, sizePerPage) {
        const currentIndex = (page - 1) * sizePerPage;
        this.options.page = page;
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.fetchWorkerJobsCount.cancel(); //not working
        this.props.fetchWorkerJobs.cancel(); //not working
        console.log(this.props);
        this.fetchWorkerJobs(page, sizePerPage, this.where, this.sort);
      }

    onSizePerPageList(sizePerPage) {
        const currentIndex = (this.state.currentPage - 1) * sizePerPage;
        this.options.sizePerPage = sizePerPage;
        this.fetchWorkerJobs(this.options.page, sizePerPage, this.where, this.sort);
      }

    onFilterChange(filterObj) {

        let where = {};
        for (const key in filterObj) {
            where[key] = filterObj[key].value;
        }
        this.where = where;
        this.fetchWorkerJobs(this.options.page,this.options.sizePerPage,this.where, this.sort);
      }

    onSortChange(sortName, sortOrder) {
        this.sort = sortName + " " + sortOrder;
        this.fetchWorkerJobs(this.options.page,this.options.sizePerPage,this.where, this.sort);
      }



    fetchWorkerJobs(page, size, where, sort){
        let self = this;   
        this.props.fetchWorkerJobsCount(where).then(function(response){
            let data = response.payload.data;
            if(data.header.error){
                //@todo show error on input form
                //self.handleShowError(data.header.message);                
            }else{
                return data.body.recordset.record;

            }
        })
        .then((count)=>{
            this.props.fetchWorkerJobs(page, size, where, sort).then(function(response){
                let data = response.payload.data;
                if(data.header.error){
                    //@todo show error on input form
                    //self.handleShowError(data.header.message);                
                }else{
                    self.options.page = page;
                    self.options.sizePerPage = size;
                    self.workerJobs = data.body.recordset.record;
                    self.setState({
                        data : data.body.recordset.record,
                        totalDataSize : count
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    }

    moveElement() {
      //store a this ref, and
      var _this = this;
      //wait for a paint to do scrolly stuff
      window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
          if($(".react-bs-table-tool-bar").length > 0){
              if($(".react-bs-table-tool-bar .react-bs-table-sizePerPage-dropdown").length <= 0){

                  $(".react-bs-table-sizePerPage-dropdown").prependTo(".react-bs-table-tool-bar");
              }
          }
      });
    }

    renderTable(services) {

        return (
            <BootstrapTable
                keyField="worker_job_id"
                data={services}
                remote
                //multiColumnSearch
                fetchInfo={ { dataTotalSize: this.state.totalDataSize } }
                options={this.options}
                pagination
                striped
                hover
                //insertRow
                //search
                tableHeaderClass="table-vf thead"
                exportCSV
                tableContainerClass="report_workerjobs"
            >
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="worker_job_id" dataSort={true} width={`60px`}>
                    #
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="job" filter={ { type: 'SelectFilter', options: jobType } }>Job</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="filename">Filename</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn
                    dataField="flag"
                    filter={{ type: 'TextFilter', defaultValue: 'C' }}
                    width={`60px`}
                >
                    Flag
                </TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="total_time_taken" width={`125px`}>Total Time Taken</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="output" width={`100px`}>Analysis</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="ts_created">Created</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="ts_updated">Finished</TableHeaderColumn>     
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="comms_matrix_id" width={`60px`}>#CM</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="visible_lines" width={`100px`}>Visible Lines</TableHeaderColumn>
                <TableHeaderColumn 
                    dataField="security_flows" 
                    width={`100px`} 
                    thStyle={{
                        whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
                        whiteSpace: '-moz-pre-wrap',
                        whiteSpace: '-pre-wrap',
                        whiteSpace: '-o-pre-wrap',
                        wordWrap: 'break-word'
                        }} 
                >
                    Security Flows
                </TableHeaderColumn>

            </BootstrapTable>
        );
    }

    render() {
        if(!this.runOnce && this.props.isReady){             
            this.runOnce = true;
            this.fetchWorkerJobs(this.options.page, this.options.sizePerPage, this.where, this.sort);
        }

        let table = <div>Loading...<i className="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>;
        if ( Object.keys(this.props.reportsWorkerJobs).length > 0) {
            table = this.renderTable(this.state.data);
            this.moveElement();
        }

        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <div className="row-fluid top-buffer">{table}</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        reportsWorkerJobs: state.reportsWorkerJobs,
        reportsWorkerJobsCount: state.reportsWorkerJobsCount
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(
        { fetchWorkerJobs, fetchWorkerJobsCount },
        dispatch
    );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WorkerJobs);
```

I want to cancel previous pagination requests etc.. I need to cancel

```
this.props.fetchWorkerJobsCount.cancel(); //not working
        this.props.fetchWorkerJobs.cancel(); //not working
```

I have tried to export the variable from action file and import into component but that does not work

**actions.js**

```
export const FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT_CANCEL = wjc_cancel;
```

**component**

```
...
import { fetchWorkerJobs, fetchWorkerJobsCount, FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT_CANCEL, FETCH_WORKERJOBS_CANCEL } from '../../actions';
...
onPageChange(page, sizePerPage) {
        const currentIndex = (page - 1) * sizePerPage;
        this.options.page = page;
        FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT_CANCEL();
        FETCH_WORKERJOBS_CANCEL();
        this.fetchWorkerJobs(page, sizePerPage, this.where, this.sort);
      }
```

error i get is `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _actions.FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT_CANCEL) is not a function`

Update

I tried to pass it as variable to actions function but some requests seem to get through. what I am doing is pressing the next button on pagination very fast. most get cancelled but some do not.

[image: some not being cancelled fast enough]

```
export function fetchWorkerJobs(page, size, where, sort, cancelled) {
    if(cancelled){
        wj_cancel();

    }
    const request = axios.get(`/api/user/report/comms/matrix/upload/format/json?quiet=1&page=`+page+`&size=`+size+`&where=`+JSON.stringify(where)+`&sort=`+sort,{
        cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
            // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
            wj_cancel = c;
        })
    }); 
    return {
        type: FETCH_WORKERJOBS,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need access to the `source` variable in order to cancel it.

Alternatively you could cancel the previous request when you create a new one (*this seems to be your use case*).

Something like the following (*using the executor function syntax: https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation so you get a new token for each request*)

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import $ from 'jquery';
var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let wj_cancel, wjc_cancel;

export const FETCH_WORKERJOBS = 'fetch_workerjobs';

export function fetchWorkerJobs(page, size, where, sort) {
  wj_cancel && wj_cancel();
  const request = axios.get(`/api/user/report/comms/matrix/upload/format/json?quiet=1&page=` + page + `&size=` + size + `&where=` + JSON.stringify(where) + `&sort=` + sort, {
    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
        // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
        wj_cancel = c;
      }
  });
  return {
    type: FETCH_WORKERJOBS,
    payload: request
  };
}

export const FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT = 'fetch_workerjobs_count';

export function fetchWorkerJobsCount(where) {
  wjc_cancel && wjc_cancel();
  const request = axios.get(`/api/user/report/comms/matrix/upload/count/format/json?quiet=1&where=` + JSON.stringify(where), {
    cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
        // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
        wjc_cancel = c;
      }
  });
  return {
    type: FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

Comment: how woudl i access `let wj_cancel, wjc_cancel;` from my component

Comment: @shorif2000 the idea is that the `fetchWorkerJobsCount` and `fetchWorkerJobs` would call it on their own when you try to make a new fetch.

Comment: oh... that was not very clearly written anywhere. had me puzzled.

Comment: @shorif2000 sorry for that, i implied it in the ".. *you could cancel the previous request when you create a new one* .." part. It is already in the code above the `axios.get` calls.

Comment: @shorif2000 alternatively you could export the two variables and import them for use in your component.

Comment: i have added an update of the export and import but it does not work

Comment: The `export const FETCH_WORKERJOBS_COUNT_CANCEL = wjc_cancel;` exports another variable that has the initial value of `wjc_cancel` which would be `undefined`. You need to export the `wjc_cancel` directly. `export wj_cancel;`

Comment: I have tried your example in the answer. to test i have clicked continuously on pagination pages but its hard to see if it is working. it cancels sometimes but it also gets resolved super fast. so not sure if my api is request is resolved really quick or if i got something wrong wit the code.

Answer (score 7):

Here is code that can be used:

```
// get info in component
useEffect(() => {
    const cancelToken = customAxios.CancelToken.source();
    dispatch(fetchStream(match.params.id, cancelToken.token));

    return () => {
        cancelToken.cancel(`Cancel fetchStream ${match.params.id}`)
    }
}, []);

// where fetchStream in store/actions/streams.js
export const fetchStream = (id, cancelToken) => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const {data: stream} = await axios.get(`/streams/${id}`, {
            cancelToken
        });

        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_STREAM,
            payload: stream
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("fetchStream get error ", e);
    }
};
```