# How to cancel axios call in react-redux action on change of search text?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

I am using redux for doing api call and searching on basis of text. I am dispatching  action onChange of text and want to cancel the alternate api calls.
Here is my code for Input -

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { searchData } from "./action";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    dispatch(searchData({ searchText : e.target.value }))
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input onChange={handleChange}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Code for action -

```
export const searchData = ({ searchText = "" }) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(initiate());
    const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, {
      query: queryToCall(searchText)
    });
    dispatch(success(response));
  };
};
```

I have tried this solution -
[how to cancel previous axios with redux in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233860/how-to-cancel-previous-axios-with-redux-in-react)

Also tried to pass cancelToken as parameter in action but it doesn't seem to work.
How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If this is for something like an autocomplete input, the simple solution is to only keep the most recent response and ignore the results of all previous requests.

```
export const searchData = ({ searchText = "" }) => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const startedAt = Date.now();
    // Adjust this action to write this timestamp in the state,
    // for example state.mostRecentSearchStartedAt (initialState 0)
    dispatch(initiate(startedAt));
    
    const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, {
      query: queryToCall(searchText)
    });

    // Ignore response if it belongs to an outdated search request
    // - a more recent search has been triggered in the meantime.
    if (getState().mostRecentSearchStartedAt === startedAt) {
      dispatch(success(response));
    }
  };
};
```